# Electric field around a disc with given density

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, coulombs-law

Given the disc with radius $R$ with its centre being $(0,0,0)$ and $\sigma(r,\phi) =\sigma_0 \frac{r}{R}\cos^2(\phi)$, I have to find the electric field at point $(0,0,L)$ where $L\gg R$.

So I tried using $ dE=\frac{kdq}{d^2}\cdot\frac{(-r\cos\phi,-r\sin\phi,L)}{\sqrt{r^2+L^2}}$ with $ d=\sqrt{L^2+r^2}$.

For $dq$ I looked at a small part of the disc and figured that $dq=\sigma_{0}\left(\frac{r}{R}\right)\cos^{2}\left(\phi\right)r\,dr\,d\phi,$
with $ 0<r<R$ and $0<\phi<2\pi.$

Ignoring the $x,y$ components because the problem has symmetry gives me:$$ E_{z}=\int\limits _{0}^{R}\int\limits _{0}^{2\pi}\frac{k\sigma_{0}L\cos^{2}\left(\phi\right)r^{2}d\phi dr}{R\left(L^{2}+r^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}=\frac{\pi k\sigma_{0}L}{R}\int\limits _{0}^{R}\frac{r^{2}}{\left(L^{2}+r^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}dr\\=\frac{\pi k\sigma_{0}L}{R}\left[R-L\arctan\left(\dfrac{R}{L}\right)\right].$$
When $L\gg R $ this becomes $ \frac{\pi k\sigma_{0}L}{R}\left[R-L\arctan\left(0\right)\right]=\frac{\pi k\sigma_{0}L}{R}\left(R\right)=\pi k\sigma_{0}L.$

The correct answer should be $ \frac{k\sigma_{0}R^{2}\pi}{3L^{2}} $, where did I go wrong?

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093) for "check my work" questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is $L$ along the $z$-direction? Not that is matters. Since the correct answer goes as $1/L^2$, you are looking a pure monopole field (or the cylindrical field equivalent).

A monopole field is radially outward with magnitude:
$$ E = k\frac q{r^2},$$
where $q$ is the total charge. It suffices to show that:
$$ q=\int\sigma(r,\phi)dr d\phi = \frac 1 3 \sigma_0 \pi R^2 =\frac 1 3 (\sigma_0A),$$
where the $1/3$ arises from the integral over $\sigma(r)\times (r\,dr) \propto r\times r\,dr =r^2\,dr $.

Comment: This was brilliantly easy doing your way, thanks.

Comment: @DannyBlozrov knowing the answer helps.